# Dimensional curvature identities

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In a series of papers ([1](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.1883), [2](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.1380), [3](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.5481)) P. Gilkey et al. discuss certain identities satisfied by the curvature tensor of a (pseudo)-Riemannian metric.

Contrary to the Bianchi or Ricci identities, these ones only hold in certain dimensions. The simplest of them is well-known: on any Riemannian manifold of dimension $2$, the Einstein tensor vanishes, i.e.
$$ Ricc = \frac{r}{2} \, g \ , $$ where $Ricc$ and $r$ denote the Ricci tensor and the scalar curvature of $g$, respectively.

More generally, for any Riemannian manifold of even dimension $n = 2k$, the authors consider $k$ identities satisfied by the curvature, and characterize them as the only identities satisfying certain homogeneity condition.

Nevertheless, all these identities are *second-order*, i.e., only involve second-derivatives of the metric $g$. My question is:

- Does anybody know any "higher-order" dimensional curvature identity?

As far as I can follow the reasoning of the paper, I guess there should be plenty of them, but I cannot come up with any particular expression.

---

NOTE: For the curious reader, the identities studied by Gilkey et al. are related to the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem: in even dimension, the integral of the Pfaffian is a topological constant, hence independent of the Riemannian metric; therefore, the Euler-Lagrange equations of this variational problem are identically zero, thus yielding a curvature identity.

Comment: Maybe you could ask Peter Gilkey by email?

Comment: Your question can be reduced to this one: https://mathoverflow.net/q/379629

Comment: See aslo 2.2 in  “Riemannian metrics with the prescribed curvature tensor and all its covariant derivatives at one point”. by O. Kowalski and M. Belger (Math. Nachr. 168 (1994), pp. 209–225.)